# jquery submit() not working with handle?

Tags: jquery

Why does this work:

```
    $("form[data-remote].edit_item").submit();
```

But this does not?

```
    $("form[data-remote].edit_item").submit(function() {
             alert('goo')
    });
```

Comment: It is possible that your page unloads before the submit() handler executes?

Comment: no unloading going on, It's all AJAX save

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this, you're *invoking* the `submit` event:

```
$("form[data-remote].edit_item").submit();
```

With this you're *attaching a handler to* the `submit` event:

```
$("form[data-remote].edit_item").submit(function() {
   alert('goo');
});
```

---

With the second you're saying "alert when the `submit` event happens"...you're not saying "hey you, submit", for that you still need to call [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), or what it's a shortcut for: [`.trigger("submit")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)...like this:

```
$("form[data-remote].edit_item").submit(function() {
   alert('goo');
}).submit();
```

...but at that point, why not just alert separately? like this:

```
$("form[data-remote].edit_item").submit();
alert('goo');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon after the alert call.

Comment: While true, it doesn't affect the outcome at all here :)

Answer (score 0):

does this display your `alert()`?

```
$("form[data-remote].edit_item").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('goo');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one submits the form, the second one sets up a function callback to execute when the form is submitted.